# How can I get the training logs from Caffe every 1000 or so iterations?

Tags: caffe

I am currently working neural net. I wish to be able to observe the progress of the training in real time. Is there a way to make caffe update a log after every batchM

Answer (score 0):

The solver can be configured to print the training loss every N iterations. To do so, add/change the `display: <N>` to you solver prototxt file.